# Debug installation of pyenv-virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to install and use pyenv-virtualenvwrapper to create a virtual python environment.  I am on ubuntu 13.04.

```
$ pyenv version
2.7.5 (set by /home/evan/.pyenv/version)

$ pip freeze | grep virtual
virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.1.1

$ ls ~/.pyenv/plugins/
pyenv-virtualenvwrapper python-build version-ext-compat

$ pyenv virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper not installed.

$pyenv which virtualenvwrapper.sh
pyenv: virtualenvwrapper.sh: command not found

$ pyenv whence virtualenvwrapper.sh
$

$ which $HOME/.pyenv/shims/pip
/home/evan/.pyenv/shims/pip
```

Has anyone else worked their way through this issue? I would like to create a virtual environment.  In pythonbrew which I used in prior versions of ubuntu, I would have just..

```
$ mkvirtualenv dssg
$ workon dssg
(dssg) $
```

Here:

```
$ mkvirtualenv dssg
mkvirtualenv: command not found
$ pyenv mkvirtualenv
mkvirtualenv: no such command `mkvirtualenv'
$ pyenv virtualenvwrapper mkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper not installed.
$
```

Comment: You should add some specific context as to where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I just want to create and use a virtual env for the specific version of python referenced in the code above.

Comment: So where did you get stuck? You should edit your question to be more specific. What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a virtual environment in a non-system (virtual) version of python under the control pyenv, you need to use a slightly different syntax.  From the [documentation of virtualenv plugin](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv)

$ pyenv virtualenv venv33

For me this only works if I am in the directory of the non-system version of python ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5.  I have a tutorial that walks you through this at http://mofj.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2014/01/20/ubuntu-set-up-a-virtual-environment-with-ipython-numpy-and-pandas/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something really silly an unintuitive about how virtualenvwrapper works on Ubuntu. On most operating systems the following command will let you source virtualenvwrapper.sh:

```
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

However, for some strange reason, it is instead stored in `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper`

So if you want access to the `mkvirtualenv` command you need to source it in the following way:

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualanevwrapper
```

Depending on how often you make virtualenvs it might be worth making an alias for that just because it's unintuitive, but I usually don't use this enough that it's worth it.

In the future if you're trying to locate something you should read up on the `find` and `locate` functions.

Comment: This does not work for me.  I am in a virtual python environment not the system python. Thanks.

Comment: If you're already in a virtual environment your question doesn't make any sense. You don't make a virtualenv from a virtualenv. That's like installing a VM on a VM, and also it won't work since virtualenvs are system level and not solely within python. Deactivate your current virtual env and make a new one if that's what you're trying to do. If that not what what you're trying to do then rewrite your question.

Comment: I had done exactly this, installed a virtal environment for the libraries inside a non-system version of python.  I followed this tutorial [http://technomilk.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/setting-up-our-django-site-environment-with-pythonbrew-and-virtualenv/] which worked in ubuntu 12.04.  However there is no more developement of pythonbrew and the author recommends pyenv suite [https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew] (see deprecated in the Readme.md).

Comment: Your link is broken. `mkvirtualenv` is a function of `virtualenvwrapper.sh` that constructs a new python virtual environment. You seem to be very confused, but you don't need pyenv at all. There's a reason `virtualenvwrapper` was made.

Comment: Sorry the link is broken because it included the right hard bracket. Here are the correct links. [http://technomilk.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/setting-up-our-django-site-environment-with-pythonbrew-and-virtualenv/ ]  The second link is [https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew ]. It is my understanding that isolates python libraries and pyenv (and previously pythonbrew isolate different versions of python itself.

Comment: @user894203 You are mistaken in your interpretation. pyenv/pythonbrew don't use virtualized python environments, they allow your system to switch between different versions of python. (You can also do the same thing pretty trivially with a few lines of bash script). Outside of specialized cases you aren't going to need to actively manage your python version, for using Django you should not bother. A virtualenv lets you have multiple python set ups, since modules sometimes break backwards compatibility. Python only does this between 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes I want to switch between versions of python and have virtualenvs within each version. Any help to achieve that would be most appreciated.